# Angular Material Stepper Last Step accessible when everything is done without linear

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

Like the title says I want to make the last step just accessible when the rest is already filled.

My Steps looks like this: 1-Login Details -> 2-Personal Details -> 3-Check

It would make no sense to get to the check without having all details. But I don't want to do it linear so that you can switch between login and personal details like you want to.

HTML:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
      <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
        <mat-icon>check</mat-icon>
      </ng-template>
<mat-step [stepControl]="registerForm" errorMessage="{{ 'REGISTRATION.STEPPER_ERROR_LOGIN' | translate }}"> 
...
 </mat-step>

<mat-step [stepControl]="personalForm" errorMessage="{{ 'REGISTRATION.STEPPER_ERROR_PERSONAL' | translate }}">
...
</mat-step>

<mat-step [stepControl]="registerForm && personalForm" errorMessage="Überprüfung steht aus">
...
</mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

TS:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration',
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration.component.scss'],
  providers: [{
    provide: STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: { showError: true }
  }]
})
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:

Add `optional` to the first `mat-step`

`<mat-step [stepControl]="registerForm" errorMessage="{{ 'REGISTRATION.STEPPER_ERROR_LOGIN' | translate }}" optional>`

Solution 2:

1. Set `mat-stepper` or `mat-horizontal-stepper` to be linear, eg.:

   `<mat-horizontal-stepper linear="true">`
2. Add `completed` property to the first `mat-step`. It allows you to go to the second step without filling the form.

   `<mat-step completed>`
3. Don't use `stepControl` on the fist `mat-step`. Eg.

   `<mat-step` <strike>`[stepControl]="firstFormGroup"`</strike> `completed>`

Example code:

a) HTML:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper linear="true" #stepper>
<mat-step completed>
  <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Last name, First name" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</mat-step>
<mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
  <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your address</ng-template>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Address" formControlName="secondCtrl" required>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</mat-step>
<mat-step>
  <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
  You are now done.
  <div>
    <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
    <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
  </div>
</mat-step>
```

b) TS:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

/**
 * @title Stepper overview
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'stepper-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'stepper-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['stepper-overview-example.css'],
})
export class StepperOverviewExample implements OnInit {
  isLinear = false;
  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay that works, but I also want to use errorMessages like I do at the moment and that won't work because for the control it's completed because there is no control anymore. Urgh seems like I have to decide what's more important for me I guess.

Comment: Updated my answer. Just add `optional` to the first mat-step

Comment: If you want the optional to disappear then just add this in the CSS: 
`::ng-deep .mat-step-optional {
  display: none;
}`